# is setOnClickListener removes the previous Listeners in android?

Tags: android, view, onclick, onclicklistener

I am writing a code, where I will use more [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) for one View but I want it to have only one `onClickListener` at time. 
So my question is: Is it enough if I always call `myView.setOnClickListener(MyListener)` or do I need to call `myView.setOnClickListener(null)` always before I set a new listener to the view?

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) says only that it registers a callback, doesn't say anything about the previously registered callbacks.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If you register again, old will be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is: Is it enough if I always call
>   myView.setOnClickListener(MyListener)?

yes it is enough. the setter, as the name says, `sets` (`assigns`) the reference you are providing as parameter, overriding any precedent assigned references.

> The documentation says only that it registers a callback, doesn't say
>   anything about the previously registered callbacks.

It doesn't because the name implies already it